# Please shade out ignored tags when doing a search for questions with zero answers

Tags: feature-request, search, ignored-tags

If I do a search for Ruby questions without answers, questions with tags I ignore are not shaded out. For example, doing `[ruby] answers:0` shows [Stripe remember me everywhere not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664300/stripe-remember-me-everywhere-not-displayed) un-shaded, even though "ruby-on-rails" is an ignored tag.

I assume the rationale for not ignoring questions when you're doing a search is that you're searching for content, and you don't want to hide content. But if you've got `answers:0` in your search, it's very likely that you're searching for questions, not searching for content.

I've heard of other ways to search for questions with no answers, or no upvoted answers. There's the "unanswered" tab for a tag. But that sorts by question votes, not by how new the question is, or how active the question is. There's also https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags , but that seems to sort by question votes, not by newness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ruby to find questions with no upvoted answers in your tag, and then click on the "newest" tag.

That has questions with ignored tags shaded out.